# how to increase size of a cell and keep it fixed in gnuplot

Tags: size, gnuplot, cell

I have posted similar question 3 days ago ("increase pixel size"). However, so far, no answer. Therefore, I decided to start a new thread and make my question more precise.

I have 2D matrix 68 per 68 and I want to make a heat map from it. I did it, but 
the problem is that for the matrix of this size cells become really small.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4ygdg0csa7d5y5/TEST_68x68.png?dl=0

Therefore, I want to increase size of a cell, for example twice and keep it fixed.
So, my idea was to define a matrix, which will be twice bigger than 68/68 that is 68*2/68*2 and then increase size of cell accordingly. I tried it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/spwo6zik1f077z3/TEST_incresedTwice.png?dl=0
However, dimensions of cells are also scaled. They have the same size like in the standard 68/68 matrix (see the first link). The cells also move. For example, instead of being bound to their original coordinates, all my values are moved by 10. I know why. The question is, how to prevent GNUPLOT from doing it?

Summarizing, I want to increase size of cells, keep their dimensions fixed and plot these bigger cells on a 68*2/68*2 matrix.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Thank you.

Code below:

```
 set terminal png transparent truecolor nocrop enhanced size 2000,2000 font     
 "arial bold,30” 
 set output 'TEST_now.png'
 set size ratio 1
 set palette rgbformulae -21,-22,-23
 set xrange[-0.5:136.5]
 set yrange[-0.5:136.5]
 plot "matrix.dat" matrix using ($1*2):($2*2):3 with image not
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `image` plotting style you get 68×68 pixels, all of the same size. You cannot increase the size of single pixels.

In your data file you have many entries with `0.00` which is what makes the white pixels. And, in the data file you have section like

```
0.000 0.457 0.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
0.000 0.073 0.337 0.000
0.002 0.993 0.916 0.000
0.000 0.003 0.000 0.000
```

and here I wouldn't even know how you would expect the pixels to be enlarged.

On possibility would be to plot every pixel as square point and use a large point size. This however leads to overlapping of immediately neighbouring points. To reduce this problem a bit, you could first draw all points with `0 < z <= 0.1`, then those with `0.1 < z <= 0.2` and so on:

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent truecolor nocrop enhanced size 2000,2000 font "arial bold,30” 
set output 'TEST_now.png'
set size ratio 1
set palette rgbformulae -21,-22,-23
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set offsets 1,1,1,1
plot for [i=1:10] "matrix.dat" matrix using ($3 > 0.1*(i-1) && $3 <= 0.1*i ? $1 : 1/0):2:3 with points pt 5 ps 7 palette notitle
```

[image]

I don't know of any "smarter" solution, even when disregarding gnuplot's abilities.